# Finding greatest value of $m!$ less than a given value.

Tags: inequality

How do I solve the equation of type $m! < 10^{15}$.  I want to find the maximum $m$ for which the inequality holds true!

Comment: For small numbers : Brute force, for large numbers : Stirling approximation

Comment: Note that even for the two term Stirling approximation, the result is still not in closed form in terms of elementary functions...but it can be handled numerically pretty conveniently.

Comment: +1 for Stirling Approximation. Check it out: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation#Stirling.27s_formula_for_the_gamma_function

Comment: Solve $x\ln x -x = 15 \ln 10$ for $x$ to get a rough idea

Comment: For small $m$, lookup a precomputed table of factorials.

Comment: Might as well point out that for natural numbers $m$, this gives $m < 18$.

Answer (score 1):

By Stirling's approximation if $c \geq 2$ then the nonnegative solution to $\Gamma(x+1)=c$ is between the solution to

$$x \ln(x)-x+\frac{1}{2} \ln(x) + \frac{1}{2} \ln(2\pi)=\ln(c)$$

and the solution to

$$x \ln(x)-x + \frac{1}{2} \ln(x) + 1=\ln(c)$$

Both of these equations can be quickly solved numerically (e.g. using Newton's method with an initial guess of $x=\ln(c)$). You can piece together the answer to your question from here, since $\Gamma(x+1)$ is increasing for $x \geq 2$ and $\Gamma(n+1)=n!$.

Note that at least until $c$ is larger than $2^{64}-1 \approx 1.8 \cdot 10^{19}$, it will be easier to just brute force it by computing factorials and comparing. It may be easier to do the above after that, since then you won't be able to store your factorials as 64 bit unsigned integers.

Answer (score 0):

In the same spirit as Ian's answer, looking for the zero of $$f(x)=x \ln(x)-x+\frac{1}{2} \ln(x) + \frac{1}{2} \ln(2\pi)-\ln(c)$$ we can also get an estimate solving first $$g(x)=x \ln(x)-x+ \frac{1}{2} \ln(2\pi)-\ln(c)=0$$ the solution of which being given in terms of [Lambert function](1] $$x=\frac{2 \log (c)-\log (2 \pi )}{2\, W\left(\frac{2 \log (c)-\log (2 \pi )}{2
   e}\right)}$$ and use the approximation $$W(z)=L_1-L_2+\frac{L_1}{L_2}+\cdots\qquad \qquad{L_1=\log(z)\qquad L_2=\log(L_1)}$$

So, we have an estimate (it is an underestimate of the solution) $x_0$ and we can start Newton method $$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$$ using $$f'(x)=\frac{1}{2 x}+\log (x)$$

For illustration purposes, let us try using $c=10^{15}$. The first step gives $x_0=17.1573$. Newton iterates will then be 
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & 17.1573 \\
 1 & 17.3619 \\
 2 & 17.3615 
\end{array}
\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

To solve $x \ln(x)-x+\frac{1}{2} \ln(x) + \frac{1}{2} \ln(2\pi)=\ln(c)$ numerically you can take advantage of the slow variation of $\ln (x)$ to use fixed point iteration.  Write it as $x_{i+1}=\frac{\ln(c)-\frac 12\ln(2\pi)}{\ln(x_i)-1}$ and start with any convenient $x_0$  As soon as the integer parts of the $x_i$ converge you are done.